# Hosting .net API in linux box

Tags: c#, .net, linux, unix, iis

I have **created few APIs in C#** (.net framework **4.5.2)** (***Not .net core ..i hope***) , which is published from visual studio and hosted Windows Server IIS server . It is up and running fine.

Now can i put the same api published file in **Linux wwwroot folder**,

> will it work?

Comment: No. It needs to be published targeting `.Net Core`. That's the point of `.Net Core` to be `cross-platform`

Comment: I am not seeing any option while publishing as .net core , where do i get it ?

Comment: 1. You need to have .Net Core installed on your dev machine, Visual Studio 2017 comes equipped with it, 2. You will need to re-do your project as dot net core and dot net framework are different.                                                        3. This is why I have moved into developing everything I can in `.Net Core`

Comment: You can easily migrate to .NET Core from .NET Framework 4.5 WebApi and run it on variety OSes and even in Docker and Kubernetes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Framework is Windows-only. .NET Core is cross-platform. So your app should target .NET Core for you be able to run it on Linux.

Download the [.NET Core SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1) and try to create a new project using the [command-line interface (CLI) tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/?tabs=netcore2x). You could also use Visual Studio 2017 15.7 or newer to create .NET Core 2.1 apps.